# I need to count the number of 'active' employees by month, but some employees have more than one job. How can I count the active employees only once?

Tags: sql, tableau-desktop

I need to calculate the number of employees by month. As you can see in the table bellow my data have five columns, one that have employee job keys, one that have employee id, one that have the status( start, end), one that shows the date, and the fifth column is the result of the calculation rolling headcount.

[image]

rolling headcount formula:

IF [ACTION]= "Start"

THEN 1

ELSEIF [ACTION] = "End" AND NOT ISNULL([TIME])

THEN - 1

END

The issue I'm having is some employees have more than one job, so they have more than one

start date and end date, but I need to count the employee as active only once.

The data I use is from a Oracle database, however I created a custom SQL query because the way the data was organized I wasn't able to count the number of employees.

This is the query:

Select EMPLOYEE_ID, SUPERVIOR_ID, POSITION_NUMBER, REPORTS_TO, JOB_OPERATING_UNIT, JOB_ACCOUNT, JOB_CLASS,
EMPLOYEE_GRADE, EMPLOYEE_CLASS, JOB_STATUS, SYNC_DATE, EMPLOYEE_RECORD_NUMBER
, 'Start' as Action
, JOB_OBSERVED_START as Time
From EMPLOYEE_JOB_FACT e

Union ALL
Select EMPLOYEE_ID, SUPERVIOR_ID, POSITION_NUMBER, REPORTS_TO, JOB_OPERATING_UNIT, JOB_ACCOUNT, JOB_CLASS,
EMPLOYEE_GRADE, EMPLOYEE_CLASS, JOB_STATUS, SYNC_DATE, EMPLOYEE_RECORD_NUMBER
, 'End' as Action
, job_observed_end as Time
From EMPLOYEE_JOB_FACT

The original data has one column for date start and one for date end.

Any ideas to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Does tableau-desktop support standard SQL?

Comment: @Kendle, yes, tableau-desktop does.

Comment: Please give your table as text. If you could create a DBfiddle that would be great. Thank you

Comment: @Kendle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5ATRnWDKNt2mooa3uHn2xe/1

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 different ways of doing this.

- In the first we add a virtual column to the table, using a case statement with the same logic as you have given in the question. We then use this column in a query with GROUP BY to retain one line per employee, checking the date in the WHERE to know who has a job at the given date.
- In the second query we use A CTE. This solution needs completing with a date filter if you can use the first method.
  You could also consider recording start and end as 1 and -1 in the action column with type int.

> ```
> Alter table Employee_Job_Fact
> add column StartEnd int generated always 
> as (case
> when Action = 'start' then 1
> when Action = 'end' then -1
> else 0 end) stored;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>   Employee_id,
>   SUM(StartEnd) startEnd,
>   MAX(`TIME`) "last Time"
> FROM
>   Employee_Job_Fact
> WHERE
>   `TIME` <= '2022-03-17 00:00:00'
> GROUP BY
>   Employee_id
> HAVING
>   SUM(StartEnd) > 0
> ORDER BY
>   Employee_ID;
> ```
>
> ```
> Employee_id | startEnd | last Time          
> ----------: | -------: | :------------------
>    40955848 |        2 | 2022-03-05 00:00:00
>   104957320 |        1 | 2022-03-12 00:00:00
>   678570955 |        1 | 2022-03-05 00:00:00
>   773731135 |        1 | 2022-03-02 00:00:00
>   820688756 |        1 | 2022-03-17 00:00:00
>   951301729 |        1 | 2022-03-17 00:00:00
> ```

> ```
> with status as (
> select
>   employee_id id,
>   sum(case when action = 'start' then 1
>   when action = 'end' then -1 end) val
> from
>   Employee_Job_Fact
> group by
>   employee_id )
> select
>   id
> from status
> where val > 0
> order by id;
> ```
>
> ```
> |        id |
> | --------: |
> |  40955848 |
> |  44969527 |
> | 104957320 |
> | 121189727 |
> | 678570955 |
> | 773731135 |
> | 820688756 |
> | 951301729 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1d3c90c1150457b408f117447dca361a)*